# .htaccess mod rewrite not working on local server weird

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

*I have read and tried everything written in similar topics on this forum so please don't mark this question as non-constructive or repetitive.*

So, here is the problem as usual.I want to use slugs and hence convert `website/trivias.php?id=xyz` to `website/xyz`

`mod_rewrite is ON` in config and also httpd configuration shows.

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-z]+) trivias.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I have tried different versions of
 `.htaccess with 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and so on. Even tried it with `trivias/reg exp` but to no use.

Thanks
Ahmar.

Comment: And what's the error you are getting, Just no rewrite?

Comment: Yeah right no rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ trivias.php?id=$1 [L]
```

without `/`

Comment: Have you tried something simple to check if it works `RewriteRule (.*) trivias.php [L]` ? Otherwise, just write random things to get an error 500.

If you enabled the module rewrite, it should work. Are you using WAMP ?